Movie about hidden dimensions and appearances being deceiving
This is a science fiction thriller that was probably made in the late 90s or early 2000s. The plot revolves around the protagonist becoming involved with a small group of experts, who specialize in something paranormal, I am not quite sure what. I have two fragments that I am confident are part of this movie. 
1) The protagonist is led by the main mentor expert into a house. When they enter, the interior of the house is impossibly large, and looks like a warehouse. This goes with a theme of "things are not always as they appear." Later on in the movie, when the protagonist returns to the house on his own, he knocks on the front door and a family comes up asking what he wants. He peeks in, and the interior is just a normal house. He leaves, very confused, but then remembers -- when driving up the circular driveway the first time, they entered clockwise; on his own just now he entered counter-clockwise. He drives his car out the way he came, then drives in again, turning left this time. When he knocks at the door this time, it is answered by a member of that expert group, as he hoped. 
2) The protagonist, the mentor, and one other expert are in an elevator. This is near the climax of the film. The antagonist of the movie somehow makes the floor of the elevator disappear. All three of them know it is happening, but the mentor says "don't look down; if you don't believe it, it won't be real." The protagonist of course looks down, and he immediately falls through the floor, but he catches on to one of the mentor's shoes! He hangs on to the shoe with both hands, as the mentor stares straight forward and tries to keep calm. The mentor then says that the protagonist needs to climb up before the elevator reaches its destination, because at that point the floor will reappear, and if the protagonist is still below the floor, he will die. The protagonist then proceeds to make the very difficult climb up the legs of the mentor, and he just barely gets his entire body over the floor before it reappears. 

I think you're looking for the 1996 movie Crossworlds with Rutger Hauer (as the mentor) that I saw a very long time ago and only have rather vague memories of.

A young man discovers that his father was from another dimension and that he is the key to the operation of a crystal that can be the deciding factor in a war crossing the dimensions.

But I remember something about a small building looking like a huge hangar from the inside and also such an elevator incident your describe.
Here's the original trailer:


 

I'm extremely impressed. That must be it. I saw a glimpse of the elevator scene in the trailer.
